# Combine delegates to be run sequentially instead of simultaneously?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates

I have come across an interesting problem which I'm having a hard time finding a solution for.

In Unity3D you can delay an action to be run on the editor, because running it right away would not do anything, i.e. it's too early for the user interface to perform it.

A single delay call is generally sufficient for most actions, but sometimes it's not. Instead of manually chaining multiple `EditorApplication.delayCall`, I would like to have a `delay` parameter instead.

But I'm having trouble figuring out the necessary code for it.

**Example:**

```
public static void RunDelayed([NotNull] Action action, int delay)
{
    if (action == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

    if (delay <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(delay));

    // 1. expected usage, action will run at next editor update
    EditorApplication.delayCall += () => { action(); };

    // 2. wanted usage, be able to delay it by N times, here by 3 times
    // as you can see, to delay by 3 times you have to build a chain of calls
    // which while simple, the number of delays are hard-coded by the amount of times
    // you pasted EditorApplication.delayCall += () =>

    EditorApplication.delayCall += () =>
        EditorApplication.delayCall += () =>
            EditorApplication.delayCall += () => { action(); };

    // 3. how can the statement above (no. 2) be modeled in a for loop instead ?
    for (var i = 0; i < delay; i++)
    {
        // here I want to do away with manually chaining
        // EditorApplication.delayCall += () => ... statements
        // in turn it allows me to delay by arbitrary N updates
    }
}
```

**Question:**

Is the creation of such delegate possible, if yes, then how ?

**References:**

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-delayCall.html

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by **3**? An example of the kind of behavior you would want in that loop would be helpful.

Comment: Just edited the last part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditorApplication.delayCall += DelayCall.ByNumberOfEditorFrames(4, () => print("Foo"));
```

Implementation:

```
public static class DelayCall
{
    public static EditorApplication.CallbackFunction ByNumberOfEditorFrames(int n, Action a)
    {
        EditorApplication.CallbackFunction callback = null;

        callback = new EditorApplication.CallbackFunction(() =>
        {
            if (n-- <= 0)
            {
                a();
            }
            else
            {
                EditorApplication.delayCall += callback;
            }
        });

        return callback;
    }
}
```

How it works:

Return a callback that maintains a counter. When the callback is invoked the counter is decremented. If the counter is greater than zero, the callback automatically re-subscribes. If the counter is less than or equal to zero then the delayed action is invoked.